# Given points extract square patches of different dimensions

Tags: sentinel-2, extract, google-earth-engine-python-api, multipatch

I have a set of point coordinates and I wish to extract a square patch around each(keeping the point at the center -say patches of 64x64~256x265 pixels-) from Sentinel-2. The points are arbitrary and not continuous.

How can I extract square patches of different dimensions (automatic and preferably pythonic)?

Comment: How do you decide the size of the square?

Comment: I would like to start with something small, that I could download as sample. I require these patches for my ML models so the smaller the more accurate. Usually the most accurate band in Sentinal-2A are (10m) ones, so a 32 by 32px would cover a land area of (320m)^2. I am detecting category/land usage so I believe 32x32px would be quite precise :)